# How to import external css into Tailwind's app.css

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, swiper.js, remix.run

I'm trying to use a 3rd party node_nodules which contains css i've tried importing it in various ways into tailwinds app.css in a remix application.
The tailwind CSS stuff is being imported and working fine.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

/* DID NOT WORK: */
/* @import '/node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
   @import '/node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
   @import '/node_modules/swiper/swiper.min.css'; */

/* DID NOT WORK: */
/* @import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
   @import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
   @import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'; */

/* DID NOT WORK: */
/* @import '~swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
   @import '~swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
   @import '~swiper/swiper.min.css'; */
```

My post.config.js looks like this:

```
    module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

When I try to do npm run build in remix it just gets output as string of the import statement:
[image]

Comment: If it's React you should be able to use `import "path/to/css";` in the component. If the CSS is global import it in `_app`.

Comment: If you're using the React Swiper component, you should be able to `import 'swiper/css';` in your app file or a component that's implementing Swiper. See: https://swiperjs.com/react

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been answered yet or not, but I found that using postcss-import with tailwind (also using Remix Vite SPA) resolved my problems. In the postcss.config.js file, make sure you have the following:

```html
export default {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': 'postcss-nesting',
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
}
```

From there, make sure you setup your imports correctly as this does use strict CSS importing as detailed here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports.

So, my tailwind.css (main css file) looks like this:

```css
@import "./libraryStyles/tailwindbase.css";
/* 
  Will need to add tailwind components, utilities, etc in separate
  file if we need to use those appropriately
*/
@import "./libraryStyles/remixRootStyle.css"
```

Where the libraryStyles folder holds both the tailwind base classes and the style I ripped from the remix github. The tailwindbase.css file looks like this for my app:

```css
@tailwind base;

@layer base {
    :root {
      --background: 0 0% 100%;
      --foreground: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
  
      --card: 0 0% 100%;
      --card-foreground: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
   
      --popover: 0 0% 100%;
      --popover-foreground: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
   
      --primary: 24 9.8% 10%;
      --primary-foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
   
      --secondary: 60 4.8% 95.9%;
      --secondary-foreground: 24 9.8% 10%;
   
      --muted: 60 4.8% 95.9%;
      --muted-foreground: 25 5.3% 44.7%;
   
      --accent: 60 4.8% 95.9%;
      --accent-foreground: 24 9.8% 10%;
   
      --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
      --destructive-foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
  
      --border: 20 5.9% 90%;
      --input: 20 5.9% 90%;
      --ring: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
   
      --radius: 0.5rem;
    }
   
    .dark {
      --background: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
      --foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
   
      --card: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
      --card-foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
   
      --popover: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
      --popover-foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
   
      --primary: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
      --primary-foreground: 24 9.8% 10%;
   
      --secondary: 12 6.5% 15.1%;
      --secondary-foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
   
      --muted: 12 6.5% 15.1%;
      --muted-foreground: 24 5.4% 63.9%;
   
      --accent: 12 6.5% 15.1%;
      --accent-foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
   
      --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
      --destructive-foreground: 60 9.1% 97.8%;
   
      --border: 12 6.5% 15.1%;
      --input: 12 6.5% 15.1%;
      --ring: 24 5.7% 82.9%;
    }
  }
   
  @layer base {
    * {
      @apply border-border;
    }
    body {
      @apply bg-background text-foreground;
    }
  }
```